# Mapbox does not showing map

Tags: javascript, css, mapbox

I had working weather app based on Mapbox but the map has not been showing for some time. The script was working and I did not changed anything except updating Mapbox scripts. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? If you need more code or a website where it is shown, let me know.

```js
import { getDayName, capEachLetter } from "/app/mapweather/js/util.js";
import { iconSelector } from "/app/mapweather/js/iconSelector.js";
// import { dayCardHTML } from "./dayCardHTML.js";

// Map API
mapboxgl.accessToken = "[REDACTED]";
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map", // container ID
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v12", // style URL
  center: [0, 30], // starting position [lng, lat]
  zoom: 2, // starting zoom
});

// global variables
const coords = {
  lat: 0,
  lng: 0
};
const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker();
const userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
const dayCardContainer = document.getElementById("dayCardContainer");

// Listener: get coords from map click
map.on("click", (e) => {
  console.log(`A click event has occurred at ${e.lngLat}`);
  getForecast(e.lngLat.lat, e.lngLat.lng);
});

// Listener: checks if user inputs co-ords or place name. If the latter, get's co-ords 
from place name.
userInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const matchCoords = userInput.value.match(
    /^[ ]*(?:Lat: )?(-?\d+\.?\d*)[, ]+(?:Lng: )?(-?\d+\.?\d*)[ ]*$/i
  );
  if (!matchCoords) {
    getCoordsFromPlace(userInput.value);
    //PROBLEM: if co-ordinates entered incorrectly, program will assume its a place and 
    try to find co - ords, and tell user to
    try co - ordinates instead.
  } else {
    getForecast(Number(matchCoords[2]), Number(matchCoords[1]));
  }
});

// uses API to convert place name to coords
function getCoordsFromPlace(place) {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get(
      `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${place}.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYnBhY2h1Y2EiLCJhIjoiY2lxbGNwaXdmMDAweGZxb`
    );
    getForecast(
      result.data.features[0].center[1],
      result.data.features[0].center[0]
    );
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status == "404") {
      alert(
        "Co-ordinate-finder server not responding. Enter co-ordinates or try again later."
      );
    } else {
      alert("Error: " + error);
    }
    console.log("Error: ", error, error.response);
  }
```

```css
.mapContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#userInput {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#userInput:focus {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}


/* MAPBOX-GL OVERRIDES */

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/mapweather/css/styles.css" />
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.1.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.1.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v5.0.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v5.0.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/app/mapweather/js/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/mapweather/css/normalize.css" />
```

Comment: 1. ***Do not post your API keys in a public forum***. Delete that ley and regenerate it. I've removed it from the question for you. 2. What debugging have you done?

Comment: Check the console. It looks like you're encountering some CORS errors. I would assume this is what the provider has changed in their configuration.